How to make a custom tree view similar to Outliner?
I want to create a custom tree view similar to Outliner.
How can I parent the Sub Group to Group and Item to Sub Group?
So the hierarchy should be like this: Group > Sub Group > Item
Also, I want to expand and collapse the view.

import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator, UIList, PropertyGroup
from bpy.props import *
import uuid


class XX_PG_item(PropertyGroup):
    use_hide: BoolProperty(
        name="Hide",
        default=False,
    )

    type: EnumProperty(
        name="Item Type",
        items=(
            ("ITEM", "Item", ""),
            ("GROUP", "Group", ""),
            ("SUB_GROUP", "Sub Group", ""),
        ),
    )

    label: StringProperty()

    parent: StringProperty()

    use_expand: BoolProperty(
        name="Expand",
        default=False,
    )


class SCENE_PG_prop(PropertyGroup):

    items: CollectionProperty(type=XX_PG_item)
    active_item_index: IntProperty(name="Active item index")


class XX_UL_item(UIList):
    def draw_item(self, context, layout, data, item, icon, active_data, active_propname, index):
        row = layout.row(align=True)

        if item.parent:
            row.label(text="", icon="BLANK1")

        row.prop(item, "use_hide", text="", icon="HIDE_ON" if item.use_hide else "HIDE_OFF", emboss=False)

        if item.type == "GROUP":
            row.prop(item, "label", text="", icon="OUTLINER_COLLECTION", emboss=False)
            row.prop(item, "use_expand", text="", icon="DOWNARROW_HLT" if item.use_expand else "RIGHTARROW", emboss=False)
        elif item.type == "SUB_GROUP":
            row.prop(item, "label", text="", icon="GROUP", emboss=False)
            row.prop(item, "use_expand", text="", icon="DOWNARROW_HLT" if item.use_expand else "RIGHTARROW", emboss=False)
        else:
            row.prop(item, "label", text="", emboss=False)
            # row.prop(item, "parent", text="parent", emboss=False)


class XX_OT_group_add(Operator):
    """Add a new item group"""

    bl_label = "Add Item Group"
    bl_idname = "xx.group_add"
    bl_options = {"INTERNAL"}

    def execute(self, context):
        prop = context.scene.prop

        item = prop.items.add()
        prop.active_item_index = len(prop.items) - 1

        uid = uuid.uuid4().hex[:7]
        item.name = f"group_{uid}"
        item.label = "Group"
        item.type = "GROUP"
        return {"FINISHED"}


class XX_OT_sub_group_add(Operator):
    """Add a new item sub group"""

    bl_label = "Add Item Sub Group"
    bl_idname = "xx.sub_group_add"
    bl_options = {"INTERNAL"}

    def execute(self, context):
        prop = context.scene.prop

        item = prop.items.add()
        prop.active_item_index = len(prop.items) - 1

        uid = uuid.uuid4().hex[:7]
        item.name = f"sub_group_{uid}"
        item.label = "Sub Group"
        item.type = "SUB_GROUP"
        return {"FINISHED"}


class XX_OT_item_add(Operator):
    """Add a new item"""

    bl_label = "Add Item"
    bl_idname = "xx.item_add"
    bl_options = {"INTERNAL"}

    def execute(self, context):
        prop = context.scene.prop

        item = prop.items.add()
        uid = uuid.uuid4().hex[:7]
        item.name = f"item_{uid}"
        item.label = "Item"
        item.type = "ITEM"

        if prop.items and (active_item := prop.items[prop.active_item_index]):
            if active_item.type == "GROUP":
                item.parent = active_item.name
            elif active_item.parent:
                item.parent = active_item.parent

        prop.active_item_index = len(prop.items) - 1
        return {"FINISHED"}


class XX_OT_item_remove(Operator):
    """Remove the active item"""

    bl_label = "Remove Item"
    bl_idname = "xx.item_remove"
    bl_options = {"INTERNAL"}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        prop = context.scene.prop
        return prop.items

    def execute(self, context):
        prop = context.scene.prop

        prop.items.remove(prop.active_item_index)
        prop.active_item_index = min(max(0, prop.active_item_index - 1), len(prop.items) - 1)
        return {"FINISHED"}


# And now we can use this list everywhere in Blender. Here is a small example panel.
class UIListPanelExample(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""

    bl_label = "UIList Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_ui_list_example"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Test"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        prop = context.scene.prop

        row = layout.row()
        row.template_list(
            "XX_UL_item",
            "",
            dataptr=prop,
            propname="items",
            active_dataptr=prop,
            active_propname="active_item_index",
            rows=5,
        )
        col = row.column(align=True)
        col.operator("xx.group_add", text="", icon="OUTLINER_COLLECTION", emboss=True)
        col.operator("xx.sub_group_add", text="", icon="GROUP", emboss=True)
        col.operator("xx.item_add", text="", icon="COLLAPSEMENU", emboss=True)

        col.separator()
        col.operator("xx.item_remove", text="", icon="TRASH", emboss=True)


classes = (
    XX_PG_item,
    SCENE_PG_prop,
    XX_UL_item,
    XX_OT_group_add,
    XX_OT_sub_group_add,
    XX_OT_item_add,
    XX_OT_item_remove,
    UIListPanelExample,
)


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)

    bpy.types.Scene.prop = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=SCENE_PG_prop)


def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)

    del bpy.types.Scene.prop


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()


I do not think? there is native support for nested tree views in the current phyton api. You could do something like Conjure SDF and just fake it by offsetting icons/text depending on the current place in the hierarchy.

Offical support for tree views with nesting might come after greasy pencil 3.0, since it has a new tree view interface that could perhaps be exposde in the phyton api, if enought people request it.
Edit - Also, I think the new bone collections is using the new tree UI as well, so I hope one day that they add it to python.
